# Click panel, change labeltext and backcolor

Tags: c#

My problem is simple. I want to click a panel in `Form1` that will cause `label1` in a `userControl1`, which will be placed upon `form2` to change to "Text".

Clicking this panel would also change the background color of said `userControl1`. I receive the error  :

> 'TileInterFaceTest.Usercontrol1.label1' due to its protection level

which frankly baffles me.

Even running the color change code separately it simply doesn't achieve the desired result.

To be clear, I'm quite a novice when it comes to C# and programming. I've been working with Visual Basic until now so the concept of classes, methods and objects are slightly confusing to me.

Here is my code for `Form1`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            UserControl1 userControl1 = new UserControl1();
            form2.Show();
            userControl1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            userControl1.LabelText = "Text";
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Code for UserControl1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public String LabelText
        {
            get
            {
                return label1.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                label1.Text = value;
            }
        }

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Generally this error occurs when you try to access `label1` which is private to user control by default, if you want to change this behavior go to properties and there is a `Modifier` property which is `private` change it to `public`.
  But in the code you have mentioned above there is no such thing, I think the error is thrown from other point of your application.
- Second one is you have created the `usercontrol` and `Form2` but you didn't add `usercontrol` to the `Form` you can add it by this code

  `form2.Controls.Add(userControl1);`